# Is there any way to change the user icon's position in a Google Map?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps-api-2

I am wondering whether is there any way to change the user's position icon. Let me show you a screenshot of my map (I'm using `GoogleMapV2`):

[image]

As you can see I managed to change the icons of some markers but I don't know how to change the blue dot (i.e. the user position) in the center of the screen. Is there any way to do it?

Thank you for your patience and consideration.

Comment: first of all hide the blue dot and try to add a Drawable in the center of screen using bounds to find the center --> i think that will resolve your problem

Comment: @B.mansouri Have you got some sample code to do it?